# Installing Aubit4GL via a source package

Tags: windows, 4gl

please tell me how to install Aubit4gl using a source package in windows i.e. I'm looking for windows commands equivalent for ./configure and make install. I can install binary but I particularly want to install from a source package for certain purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling from source on windows is a particularly complicated process involving mingw and collecting all the dependencies etc.

You're much better off grabbing one of the pre-compiled binaries.

I'd be interested to know what the "certain purposes" are that make compiling from source (for windows) a requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am trying to convert Oracle SQL to Postgresql for which I might want to modify the source package and use.